# Can iTunes auto play a song related to the one I've just listened to (not in a playlist)?

Tags: itunes, apple-music

Is there a way to let iTunes automatically play a song after listening to a song I searched (not a part of a playlist), supposedly a "related" song?

I'm aiming for something like Youtube's "Up next" feature, also available on Soundcloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently that's the radio / station feature. Just need to click the three dots button of a song and select `Start Station`.

Thing is, that button (`Start Station`) was grayed out for me. According to a random suggestion I found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7136043?start=0&tstart=0), I was able to solve it by deleting the preferences file from my library (`%USERPROFILE%\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\.iTunes Preferences.plist` on Windows 10).